# How to use useForm to validate input while using localStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to validate a simple form with a single input just for practice. I also don't want the value that the user types in the input to disappear after page refresh, for that reason, I did a little bit of searching and found out about saving that data using localStorage. After trying to implement that for a while,  I managed to do that, when I refresh the page, the value is still there. However, now, when I'm trying to validate the form using useForm from react-hook-form, It just doesn't work for some reason, when I try to use that same useForm logic with an input without using localStorage, It works just fine, but while trying to add localStorage functionality, then it doesn't. I hope I'm describing my problem at least okey, here's the code :

```
import React, {useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css"
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

const getForm = () => {
  const storedValues = localStorage.getItem("form");
  if(!storedValues) return {
      name: "",
      age: ""
    }
  return JSON.parse(storedValues);

}

function Home() {
 
 

  const [values, setValues] = useState(getForm)

  const {register, handleSubmit, watch} = useForm();

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setValues((previousValues) => ({
      ...previousValues,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    }))
  }

  const onSubmit = async data => { console.log(data); };

  useEffect(()=>{
    localStorage.setItem("form", JSON.stringify(values))
  }, [values])
  
  return (
    
    <div className="container">
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input value={values.name} onChange={handleChange} name="name" placeholder="name"  />
      <input value={values.age} onChange={handleChange} name="age" placeholder="age"/>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

    </div>
    )
}


export default Home;
```

This code works fine since I'm not adding useForm register to the input, but if I do that, then It gets buggy, like this :

```
<input value={values.name} onChange={handleChange} name="name" placeholder="name" {...register("name")} />
```

The latest code only works If I remove the value atrribute from the input, but I can't do that, If I do, I can't use localStorage anymore.

Comment: "This code works fine" Can you show us the code that doesn't work?

Comment: Sure I'll edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register), you had the syntax a little off with your `register` function.  That function takes a second argument, which is an object of props, and that is where you want to define `value`, `name` and `onChange`.

Like this:

```
<input
  placeholder="name"
  {...register("name", {
    onChange: handleChange,
    name: "name",
    value: values.name
  })}
/>
```

Here is the full code I have working on a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/useform-register-input-tol8jc?file=/src/App.js).  That's really all I changed, expect removing the `watch` import.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

const getForm = () => {
  const storedValues = localStorage.getItem("form");
  if (!storedValues)
    return {
      name: "",
      age: ""
    };
  return JSON.parse(storedValues);
};

function Home() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(getForm);

  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setValues((previousValues) => ({
      ...previousValues,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    }));
  };

  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("form", JSON.stringify(values));
  }, [values]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <input
          placeholder="name"
          {...register("name", {
            onChange: handleChange,
            name: "name",
            value: values.name
          })}
        />
        <input
          value={values.age}
          onChange={handleChange}
          name="age"
          placeholder="age"
        />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```